# AWS CodeDeploy agent is deleting files in the wrong folder during install

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops

We have an unusual setup. We use git on Azure Devops for our code repositories, and AWS for our cloud-based services. In our arsenal we have a mixture of AWS Lambda functions, along with console apps, web apps, and Windows services running on EC2 instances. We have been able to create CI/CD pipelines for all three classes of apps. For the apps running on EC2 instances we use AWS CodeDeploy. These deployments are more complicated, but they all work -- except for one.

Another unusual thing about our setup is that both our development and QA environments are on the same EC2 instance. When the CodeDeploy agent running on that instance retrieves the deployment archive, it unpacks it, reads the appspec.yml file, runs our before install script, which backs up the existing installation and shuts down any services that might be using those files. Then, the install phase updates the files in the designated environment, then deletes -- or tries to delete -- all the files in the other environment folder.

In other words, if a DEV deployment is running, it replaces the files in the DEV folder and also tries to delete the files in the QA folder. I know this sounds like a scripting problem, but I have checked all the script and yaml files no where do I reference the opposing environment.

In this case, the app is a Windows service. Normally, I get a Ruby 'Permission denied @ unlink_internal' error on a file in the other folder. As an experiment, I shut down the service in the other environment in my before install script and, as I expected, the agent deleted all the files in the other environment. It updated the files in the target environment, but left the folder in the other environment empty!

Here are my files. I suspect, the problem is being caused by something I did, but I can't, for the life of me, find it.

These are all .NET projects. In my solution I have a ConfigFiles folder set up with subfolders for each environment. Then, in my pipeline yaml file I run a script to select the correct files to move into the archive based on the git branch that is being built.

[image]

Here's the code for code for the script that selects the correct files.

[image]

Here's the Azure pipeline YAML file.

[image]

Here's my before install script:

[image]

And, finally, here is my appspec.yml file, which the CodeDeploy agent uses to know where to update the files during installation. How I want this to be the wrong path, but in the deployment archive, the environment specific values are all exactly right.

[image]

Any ideas on this one would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code sample but wrap it into a code block instead

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem where deployment of an app deletes files from another app in another folder unexpectedly. My solution is to use different deployment groups for each app, even though they are deploying to the same EC2 instance.

Comment: This is the only thing that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying many apps on the same EC2 instance using the same deployment group results in files/folder deletion on other deployed projects.

From AWS Technical Support:

> The reason is that codedeploy creates a clean up file by the format '[deployment group 1 ID]_cleanup" in the directory '/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-instructions' everytime a deployment is made to the deployment group and this file deletes all the files that had been installed during the previous deployment made to the deployment group. Since the deployment group is the same in your case, when you make a deployment to the deployment group which installs files to the folder "/var/www/project1", files installed by the previous deployment in the folder "/var/www/project2" are being cleaned up and vice versa which is an expected mechanism of the codedeploy agent.
>
> You can find the explaination here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent.html#codedeploy-agent-install-files
>
> Please consider creating two different applications/deployment groups
> and configure the two pipelines to use different
> applications/deployment groups which should fix your problem.