# AWS CodeDeploy, Files getting removed from other folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

[image]

I have a code pipeline setup for React application. Whenever a new build is updated(In client folder) , the files(directories remain) are getting removed the server folder.
Tried seeing the event logs in code deploy, not able to get much info
could someone please help me with this?

**appSpec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux 
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/client
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
  - location: scripts/after.sh
    timeout: 300
    runas: root
```

**buildSpec.yml**

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: "development"

phases:
  install:
 

       runtime-versions:
          nodejs: 14
    
      pre_build:
        commands:
          - npm install
    
      build:
        commands:
          - npm run build-qa
    artifacts:
      type: zip
      paths:
        - './build/**/*'
        - './appspec.yml'
        - './scripts/**/*'
```

**after.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/client
echo '---Process started---'
echo '---Taking backup---'
sudo rm -r backup_*
sudo mv /home/ubuntu/client/deploy /home/ubuntu/client/backup_$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
echo '---backup complete---'
echo '---renaming build---'
sudo mv /home/ubuntu/client/build /home/ubuntu/client/deploy
echo '---renaming complete---'
```

Edit: I was running two CI/CD pipelines (One for Frontend and other was backend) both running for the same EC2 instance, I was using the same deployment group and application for both the CI/CD which was causing the issue, later I created separate deployment application and group for each CI/CD which resolved . Thanks @Shivkumar Mallesappa for the lead

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68489825/aws-codedeploy-agent-is-deleting-files-in-the-wrong-folder-during-install

Comment: Hey @ShivkumarMallesappa thanks for quick update, that thread was helpful but creating a different deployment group (within the same application) didn't help. creating a separate deployment application and group fixed the issues. Thanks

Comment: did you found an answer since ? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Hey @Greko2015GuFn, like I mentioned in my previous comment.
In my case Creating a separate/new deployment application and group fixed the issue.